# searching and updating the nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object and on searching the specific key,I want to update the original object.

```
var people= {
      "i": [
        {
          "country": "Australia",
          "list": [
            {
              "name": "ABC   ",
              "address": "AB street ",
            }
            ...
          ]
        },
        {
          "country": "Brazil",
          "list": [
            {
              "name": "XZ   ",
              "address": "AB street "
            },
           ...
          ]
        }
      ]
     ...
    };
```

I want to search by name

Comment: Why is your input not a real array?

Comment: It is a nested object with array of objects

Comment: 1. The pages map should be an array of objects for ease of use. 2. Try using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function rather than map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find for existing objects using the function `find`.

```js
var pages = {    "1":[    {      "title":"Australia",      "list":[        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"08RAH - S650 ",          "description":"S650 Combine HX"        },        {          "name":"ABC  ",          "label":"00CAH - S660 ",          "description":"S660 Combine HX"        }      ]    },   {      "title":"Brazil",      "list":[        {          "name":"XZ   ",          "label":"08RAH - S650 ",          "description":"S650 Combine HX"        },        {          "name":"W  ",          "label":"00CAH - S660 ",          "description":"S660 Combine HX"        }      ]    }  ],  "2":[    {      "title":"Australia",      "list":[        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"01KBZ - S670 ",          "description":"S670 Small Grain HillMaster Combine ZX"        },        {          "name":"DE   ",          "label":"00CAH - S660 ",          "description":"S660 Combine HX"        }      ]    },    {      "title":"United Kingdom",      "list":[        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"01KBZ - S670 ",          "description":"S670 Small Grain HillMaster Combine ZX"        },        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"00CAH - S660 ",          "description":"S660 Combine HX"        }      ]    },  ],  "3":[    {      "title":"United States",      "list":[        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"01KBZ - S670 ",          "description":"S670 Small Grain HillMaster Combine ZX"        },        {          "name":"DF   ",          "label":"01LAZ - S680 ",          "description":"S680 Small Grain Combine ZX"        }      ]    },    {      "title":"Australia",      "list":[        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"01KBZ - S670 ",          "description":"S670 Small Grain HillMaster Combine ZX"        },        {          "name":"ABC  ",          "label":"01LAZ - S680 ",          "description":"S680 Small Grain Combine ZX"        },        {          "name":"ABC   ",          "label":"01NBZ - S680 ",          "description":"S680 HillMaster™ Combine ZX"        }      ]    }  ]};

var searchedText = "AB";
var filteredPages = {};

var allPages = getFilteredPages(pages, searchedText);

function getFilteredPages(pages, searchedText) {

  Object.keys(pages).map(function(pageNumber) {
    pages[pageNumber].map(function(pageItem, index) {
      pageItem.list.map(function(item) {
        if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          if (filteredPages[pageNumber]) {
            var p = filteredPages[pageNumber].find((p) => p.title === pageItem.title);
            
            if (p) {
              p.list.push(item);
            } else {
              filteredPages[pageNumber].push({
                title: pageItem.title,
                list: [item]
              });
            }
          } else  {
            filteredPages[pageNumber] = [{
              title: pageItem.title,
              list: [item]
            }];
          }
        }
      });
    });

  });
  return filteredPages;

}


console.log('allPages >>>>>', allPages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new object filteredPages, try  to (copy and then) modify the original using delete/unshift operator. It will be easier to think about like that and you will keep the original structure.